# Adding extra authorization layer in Blazor

Tags: components, authorization, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an `AuthorizeView` component based on authentication through an `OpenID Connect` provider, but I want to add an extra layer based on some informations found about the user in the associated database after `OIDC authentication`. I am wondering whether the logic illustrated below,

1: Would be the smartest way of implementing this?

2: And if so, how to approach the task of building my own authorization view inside an already existing one?

```
<AuthorizeView>
   <Authorized>                
     <ExtraLayerAuthorized>                
         <p>Authorized through OIDC and extra layer</p>
     </ExtraLayerAuthorized>
     <NotExtraLayerAuthorized>
        <p>Authorized through OIDC, but NOT extra layer</p>
     </NotExtraLayerAuthorized>
     </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
      <p>No authorization</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note sure if the is Server or WASM.

One good way to do this is just to add an additional `ClaimsIdentity` to the existing `ClaimsPrincipal` of the standard AuthenticationStateProvider.

Here's how to do it in Server.  See the comments for an explanation of what it does.

```cs
public class MyAuthenticationStxateProvider : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        // Call the base to get the AuthState and the user provided in the Security Headers by the server
        var authstate = await base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authstate.User;

        if (user?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
        {
            // Do whatever you want here to retrieve the additional user information you want to
            // include in the ClaimsPrincipal - probably some form of Identity Service
                
            // Construct a ClaimsIdentity instance to attach to the ClaimsPrincipal
            // I just added a role as an example
            var myIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User") });
            // Add it to the existing ClaimsPrincipal
            user.AddIdentity(myIdentity);
        }

        // construct a new state with the updated ClaimsPrincipal
        // - or an empty one of you didn't get a user in the first place
        // All the Authorization components and classes will now use this ClaimsPrincipal 
        return new AuthenticationState(user ?? new ClaimsPrincipal());
    }
}
```

This is setup to use *Auth0* as the authentication provider.

```json
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Auth0": {
    "Domain": "xxxxx.eu.auth0.com",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  }
```

The service registration looks something like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services
    .AddAuth0WebAppAuthentication(options => {
        options.Domain = builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"];
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, MyAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

**Login.cshtml.cs**

```cs
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task OnGet(string redirectUri)
    {
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Auth0", new
            AuthenticationProperties
        { RedirectUri = redirectUri });
    }
}
```

**Logout.cshtml.cs**

```cs
public class LogoutModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        return Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

And then this page demonstrates logging in and out and adding the second identity when we have a valid user.

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=this.LogOut>Log Out</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.LogIn>Log In</button>
</div>
<h2>Claims</h2>

<dl>
    @foreach (var claim in user.Claims)
    {
        <dt>@claim.Type</dt>
        <dd>@claim.Value</dd>
    }
</dl>

@code {
    private ClaimsPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal();

    [CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> authStateProvider { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await authStateProvider;
        user = authState.User;
    }

    private void LogIn()
    {
        var returnUrl = NavManager.Uri;
        NavManager.NavigateTo($"login?redirectUri={returnUrl}", forceLoad: true);
    }

    private void LogOut()
    {
        var returnUrl = NavManager.Uri;
        NavManager.NavigateTo($"logout?redirectUri={returnUrl}", forceLoad: true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I set this up as proposed, I am not able to get the already existing Identity since the MyAuthentication is reached before I get to the OpenID connect signin page. But If I implement this with a click of a button it work as intended (which is big progress!!). I could probably also instantiate it with an OnGet-method for the Index-page, but doesnt seem optimal. But maybe I misunderstand smth about the flow of the Startup.cs file. I tried to put it in the order you mentioned, but still the OIDC is hit later in the process. Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

Comment: Generally, it would be very useful to be able to initiate the MyAuthenticationStateProvider as soon as I receive the ClaimsPrincipal from the OpenID connect provider but I am not sure how or when to do this. I am using cookie based authentication, if that information is relevant.

Comment: See my updated answer.  You are redirecting to the Auth provider and then getting a redirect the page so the page always reloads the new user.

Comment: Perfect! Did the job - thanks a lot!

Comment: Excellent.  Just for my curiosity, which OpenID provider are you using?

Comment: My company is the provider - a medium-sized Nordic software company. But no one seems to have used it for a Blazor application before, so it has been impossible to get help internally.